# How can author know the address of the enviroment variable with %100 certanity?

Tags: linux, fedora, buffer-overflow

In the book of *Art of Exploitation*, at page 165, it is claimed that 
[image]

However, how can it be that in this adress *0xbffffffa* be fixed ? I mean, the way author expresses himself suggests that this a general fact for any linux distribution on any machine, which is definitely not the case, so what does exactly mean ? How can he know the address of the shellcode ?

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an expert on this by any means, but my understanding is that in Linux each process has its own virtual address space with the kernel memory mapped to the addresses above 0xC0000000, the stack growing down from 0xC0000000, and the heap growing up from 0x00000000.

If so this is saying that the environment would be one of the first things on the stack -- 0x2BFFFFFA is just a few bytes below 0xC0000000 -- and that you could predict its address since there would only be a fixed number of things before it.

I think this would only apply if address space layout randomization (ASLR) isn't turned on, although as far as I understand I don't think ASLR would completely prevent this sort of exploit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Daniel. However, I don't understand how ASLR wouldn't prevent this sort of attacks ? In the last two days, I'm trying to same technique on Fedora with ASLR turned on, I haven't succeeded.

Comment: Well, with ASLR turned on the address isn't 0x2BFFFFFA any more, it's some random position instead, but there has to be *some* way of getting what this position is or the program can't work.  So you'd just have to work a little harder.

Comment: Re-reading the linked text, it may be talking about a more specific type of attack than I'm envisioning.  As I said I'm no expert here -- I'm just imagining what could be possible and haven't ever attempted to try any of these things out.